# How to make my small photo position relative to large photo?

Tags: html, css

```css
#main {
  width:100%;
  display: table;
  height:900px;
}

#left {
  width:75%;
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  border: 2px red solid;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

#right {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: black;
}

#large {
  width:80%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#small {
  width:20%;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  z-index:1;
}

#photo {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<div id="left">
        <div id="photo">
            <img src="test.jpg" id="large">
            <img src="test.jpg" id="small">
        </div> 
      </div>
  </div>
```

Right now, my small photo's position seems to relative to "photo" div.
What can I add to make small photo relative to large photo?

Comment: You can't. You can only make it relative to a parent **container**.

Comment: this is not possible.. you cant position an absolute element which is not in relative div. You can do this if can have images as background image instead them havingin `<img>` tag.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? How do you want the images to be shown? On top of each other?

Comment: What I want is large photo centre in div and small position relative to large photo.